# Formidable returns TypeError, ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE: The "path" argument is undefined

Tags: node.js, file-upload, formidable

I'm having trouble uploading files using formidable. I'm on Windows server 2016.

My code, which in its entirely is shown below, is based on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-file-using-formidable-module-in-node-js/

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const formidable = require('formidable');
   
const app = express();
   
app.post('/api/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm(
        { uploadDir: __dirname + '\\tmp',  keepExtensions: true }
    );
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        var oldPath = files.profilePic.path;
        var newPath = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')
                + '/'+files.profilePic.name
        var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath)
      
        fs.writeFile(newPath, rawData, function(err){
            if(err) console.log(err)
            return res.send("Successfully uploaded")
        })
  })
});
   
app.listen(3000, function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log('Server listening on Port 3000');
});
```

I use Postman to send a file.

When triggering the `/api/upload` API, the file sent is correctly placed in the tmp folder, but reading the path is when the problem arise:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
```

This message points to `fs.readFileSync(oldPath)`.

`console.log('files='+files)` returns `files=[object Object]`

`console.log('files.profilePic='+files.profilePic)` returns

```
C:\somepath\node_modules\formidable\src\PersistentFile.js:50
    return `PersistentFile: ${this._file.newFilename}, Original: ${this._file.originalFilename}, Path: ${this._file.filepath}`;
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newFilename')
    at PersistentFile.toString (C:\somepath\node_modules\formidable\src\PersistentFile.js:50:42)
```

All 4 referenced modules exist in node_modules folder.

Comment: Just trying this for myself but to me "files" indicates some sort of array of files. So maybe see what ```files[0]``` is

Comment: Above comment is incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change

`var oldPath = files.profilePic.path;`

to

`var oldPath = files.profilePic.filepath;`

Also make sure that you create the "uploads" folder as the code doesn't create it and it will fail without it.

EDIT: A side note is that if your environment is just spitting out [object object] when you console log an object, then probably get a new environment (visual studio code is good) that gives useful information.

Comment: Sam Dean, thank you very much! I wonder why every tutorial I've read used "path" and not "filepath", did something change recently in formidable in regard to the callback? Also, thank you for pointing out the need for a proper IDE. I'm a Java developer, so I'm used to use Eclipse. Unfortunately, I cannot get the Node plugin installed due to missing online resources during installation (weird!), so I tried Atom. The debugger here also failed to install, so I ended up with using Edge. Is Visual Studio the way to go to develop and debug Node.js apps?

Comment: No worries! I was just lucky that Visual Studio Code outputted the whole object with all of its member variables and I saw "filepath" and no "path", tried it and it worked!

Comment: @JanusEngstrøm For new node.js projects my setup is as follows. 1.) Make a new folder. 2.) Make a new git repo in that folder. 3.) Open that folder in VSC (visual studio code) 4.) Open a new terminal from VSC, "ctrl+shift+' " or "Terminal > New Terminal" 5.) In the terminal do `npm init` and fill in the options 6.) Setup a linter (to keep you to best practice code standards) using `npm i eslint` and then `npx eslint --init` and fill in the option. 7.) IN the VSC extensions get "ESLint" by Microsoft so that eslint can actually show in the code 8.) Finally I use nodemon to live reload my code

Comment: (continued) when I make changes by running `npm i nodemon` to install it and then in my "package.json", in the "scripts" section add ' "live": "nodemon index.js" ' then from the  command line you can run `npm run live` and it will run you index.js and will rerun it whenever you save changes to your code. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but since a few tutorials I've seen still have the same code or similar code to the above, I guess formidable has chnaged his api, so the above code does not work any more. With formidable v3.5.1 `files.profilePic` is an array, therefore to access filepath we have to use `files.profilePic[0].filepath`

Comment: March 2024 - this is what works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing  the
var oldPath = files.profilePic.path

to

oldPath = files.profilePic.filepath

will correct the error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Obinna. Your answer seems to be an exact copy of the already accepted answer. In what way does your answer differ from the one posted by Sam Dean?

Answer (score 0):

```
const http = require('http');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const mv = require('mv');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    const uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads');
    form.uploadDir = uploadDir;


    //check if folder does not exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(uploadDir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir);
    }

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error parsing form:', err);
        res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Internal Server Error');
        return;
      }

      const oldPath = files.file.path;
      const newPath = path.join(uploadDir, files.file.name);

      //{ mkdirp: true }: An options object passed to the mv function. The mkdirp option is used to create any necessary directories in the destination path (newPath) if they don't already exist. In other words, it automatically creates parent directories as needed.
      mv(oldPath, newPath, { mkdirp: true }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error moving file:', err);
          res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
          res.end('Internal Server Error');
          return;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('File uploaded and moved!');
      });
    });

    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.end(`
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
  `);
});

const PORT = 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Use this above code, I have used mv library to rename or move files and it worked.
On my Mac machine Rename was not working and giving same error. Maybe someone finds this solution to work.